# "Uncaught ReferenceError: items is not defined" jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery slider. After uploading my site to a web server, I get an *error* on a global variable:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: items is not defined`

There was no problem before I uploaded the site.
The error appears when I click to scroll the slider.

This is the code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.countrySelection-paddle-right').click(function () {
        $("#countrySelection-items").animate({
            scrollLeft: '+=' + items   // the error is on this line.
        });
    });
    $('.countrySelection-paddle-left').click(function () {
        $("#countrySelection-items").animate({
            scrollLeft: "-=" + items   // the error is on this line.
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: `items` is considering as variable. Have you defined it anywhere?

Comment: define varaible items :)

Comment: `there was no problem before I uploaded the site` - That suggests you've either not uploaded something (probably where `items` is defined), or that the upload means a path is now different.  Either way, check the browser console - you may see a 404 error.

Comment: @breakpoint Anyone telling him to just define the items var needs to read things properly.  That is bad advice in this case - REALLY bad advice.

Comment: @Evgeniy ^^ That.

Comment: @Archer, bad advice, really? Lets take a look at code. As you can see it wraped in dom ready callback - usually it means that its independent logic and should not relly on outer vars, then - code task is animation, so items expected to be integer, as here is an outer var dependecy its much better to handle cases as undefined, nan and define defaut var value

Comment: @Evgeniy It works before he uploads it, but then stops working.  You suggest declaring the variable again.  If you don't think that's bad advice then you should step away from the keyboard.  Tell me, how many more problems will be encountered from the fact that at least one file is clearly not referenced correctly once it's running on the server?  1?  3?  10,000?  There's no way of knowing.  Fixing **THE** problem is the right thing to do.  Ignoring the problem and just redeclaring a variable is gues what... **REALLY bad advice**.

Comment: @Archer, oh, of course not redeclaring, i mean use some local var that use global or default value. Redeclaring global var is really bad idea agree)

Comment: That alone doesn't cover the fact that the problem obviously lies elsewhere.  The fact that a variable is not locally declared is not the issue here.